# Creating a multi-dimensional array from query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am using the code below to create a multi-dimensional array from a query so that I can organize the results by category but it only gets me 2 columns (category, agency).

I am not sure how I can alter this so that I can get 4 columns (category, agency, description, website). Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
$categories = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $category = $row['category'];
    $categories[$category][] = $row['agency'];
}

<?php
    foreach ($categories as $category => $agencies)
    {
?>
    <h3><?php echo $category; ?></h3>
    <table class="chart">
<?php
    foreach ($agencies as $agency)
    {
?>
        <tr><td><?php echo $agency; ?></td></tr>
<?php
    }
?>
    </table>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could store the individual row results as an associative array:

```
$categories[$category][] = array(
      'agency' => $row['agency'], 
      'description' => $row['description'], 
      'website' => $row['website']
  );
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for. In my head this was far more complicated for some reason.